# Bash script not handling input arguments passed

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm running:

```
python Parser.py "Bot Pick Nut"
```

In linux command line via MobaXterm. This works as intended, it returns True. 
The issue I face is when run via the shell script it returns false? Can anyone advice why my shell is not giving the result to my python script correctly?

The Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
python Parser.py argv[0]
```

The command:

```
 ./Shell.sh "Bot Pick Nut"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bash` *positional parameters* start from `$0` with `$1` being the first argument for the script, subsequently numbered from `$2`..`$n` with `$0` being the name of the script itself.

```
#!/bin/sh
python Parser.py "$1"
```

A simple tabulation of the arguments in `bash`,

```
$0              the first positional parameter, equivalent to argv[0] in C, see the first argument
$FUNCNAME       the function name (attention: inside a function, $0 is still the $0 of the shell, not the function name)
$1 … $9        the argument list elements from 1 to 9
${10} … ${N}   the argument list elements beyond 9 (note the parameter expansion syntax!)
$*              all positional parameters except $0, see mass usage
$@              all positional parameters except $0, see mass usage
$#              the number of arguments, not counting $0
```

Comment: Well, I feel dumb. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: I can't vote, people keep downvoting me so I don't have the rep. I couldn't mark it at the time due to the timer before you can accept an answer. I literally just got back on from having to walk half an hour to do IRL stuff.